# How to organize your .JS files in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS, and to JS in general. I come from Java world as I used to implement client side with GWT.

Now when I moved to AngularJS I face this issue:

How to organize your .js files ? In java each class has its .java file but, if this practice is implemented in JS there will be many http request to fetch .js files as each class ( Function ) resides in separate .js file.

Also, the files should be organized so that other programmers should allocate and navigate between them and be able to read and understand what are these files related to.

Comment: You can always follow the structure of the Angular-seed https://github.com/angular/angular-seed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately there are about a million ways to do this.  Since angular uses modules and all of your angular code should be in a module, IMO using javascript namespacing becomes secondary to module namespacing.

Take a look at this project ([angular-grunt-coffeescript](https://github.com/roytruelove/angular-grunt-coffeescript)).  It's my attempt to solve this problem.  I use coffeescript but the same ideas can apply to a .js project.

There is also [angular-sprout](https://github.com/thedigitalself/angular-sprout) which attempts to extend the 'angular-seed' project a bit to make it usable for big apps - angular-sprout is in js.

*UPDATE*

Yeoman looks like it might become the standard for creating a skeleton AngularJS projects, and so should provide a 'home' for everything (I personally don't use it yet).  Take a look [here](http://briantford.com/blog/angular-yeoman.html).

Answer (score 4):

For a large project i can recommend using one directory per module, and one file per "thing" (service, value, factory, controller...). Html partials should be stored in each module directory along with their respective directives or controllers.

We have been using this approach for some time, and it is really working out fine. The project is built by maven (Java is used for the backend), and all the js-files are concatenated into one file per angular application plus one file for components shared between angular applications. Check out aggregations in [yuicompressor-maven-plugin](http://alchim.sourceforge.net/yuicompressor-maven-plugin/ex_aggregation.html) if you are into maven.

Because we have several js files per module, we needed a way to create a module exactly once, and before we register the "thing" in each js-file.

The solution we came up with was adding a file called 0-module.js in each module directory with the module creation statement. yuicompressor-maven-plugin will add this first to the aggregated file.

Example file structure:

```
mymodule/
   0-module.js
      >angular.module('mymodule', []); //Create module
   MyController.js
      >angular.module('mymodule').controller("MyController", [... // Register MyController
   myTemplate.html
```

Answer (score 3):

I generally split the code into namespaces which contain classes relevant to that namespace. I put each namespace in a separate JS file.

So if you had classes called `LinkedList,BinaryTree,KDTree` etc, you could bundle them in a DataStructures namespace and save it in

```
datastructures.js
```

So you could instantiate by saying:

```
var kd = new Datastructures.KDTree();
```

By keeping the namespace name and the filename same you can find the actual piece of code easily without needing a powerful IDE as the name itself is self-decribing.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I will try to implement it this practice.

Comment: @Adio If this helped, please take the time to accept as answer :)

Comment: It helped but, it is not the best answer so far I think. I voted for the answer but can not accept it as the best answer as I don't believe it is. Or, should I  accept it no matter what  ?

Comment: @Adio no not at all, by all means wait for other answers and others' opinions.. I did not mean to pressure you in any way..Im sure my answer is not the best, no answer is.. there's always a better way :) I meant that eventually if u still feel my answer's the better of the lot, that you'll take the time to come back and accept it.

Comment: Namespacing isn't as necessary in Angular, as Angular sort of forces you into creating modules.

Comment: This is a rather bad practice because it puts a lot of weight on how it's all loaded. If you try to attach y to a non existent X, eg. x.y = .... you will end up having errors: "ReferenceError: x is not defined". I have personally tried this method and it works for very small apps, but once you modularize heavily and introduce more components it becomes a pain in the ass.

Answer (score 2):

I would recomend using [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io), as I suppose so do the developers (they advocate it quite a lot, check out their gPlus page, or this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=XOmwZopzcTA) of theirs). It allows for scaffolding (following the structure of [Angular-Seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed)), testing, live previewing via a JS server, and deployment - it concatenates all the .js files together, avoiding the issue of multiple requests. Check it out!

Answer (score 0):

Granted this question happened a while ago, for the sake of those who are asking it today, here is my collection of different best ways of using Angular including their file structures
http://www.dancancro.com/comparison-of-angularjs-application-starters/